# Calculating using modulus

Tags: c, algorithm, operators, modular-arithmetic

I am working on a problem: 
The user enters 3 tree heights and also the tree height limit. The program then calculates the amount of tree to remove.

Sample input:

```
 Tree1: 14
 Tree2: 7
 Tree3: 16

 Tree limit: 11
```

Sample output:

```
 Amount to remove: 8
```

This would usually not be too bad for me although I am still a beginner but the problem is, I am going to be calculating it WITHOUT an if statement. I must use Modulus to calculate. I have spent a very long time researching and trying different things but I just cannot seem to get it? Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post Code of your best try ?

Comment: Can you still use [`ternary`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/ternary_operator_examples.htm) statements?

Comment: what do you mean by "without if statement"?  No branching at all? Can you use loops?

Comment: I bet you can use addition and subtraction as well as modulo arithmetic...

Comment: @nos Amount to remove = `(Tree1 - 11) + (Tree3 - 11)`. We omit `Tree2` because it is `<= 11`.

Comment: `n = tree - (tree % limit)` will only work for tree excesses less than the limit.

Comment: @TooTone Whoops. I was working solution possibilities in my head and that was the transient at the time. I shouldn't think and type at the same time. Sorry.

Comment: @StarPilot no worries, I've had a few too many mistakes slip thru too recently.

Comment: `if` is the correct tool.  Other things are silly games that are not very helpful for actually learning anything.

Comment: You have stated that ***`if`*** is not allowed.  What about ***`while`*** or ***`for`*** statements?

Comment: @user2782378 - Can you edit your question so that it is clear what you have already tried and which assumptions should be made, i.e. which operators/statements *are* allowed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expression you're looking for is:

```
tree[i] % max % tree[i];
```

When `tree[i]` is greater than `max`:
*example: 16 and 11*

```
16 % 11 = 5
5 % 16 = 5
```

But when `tree[i]` is less than `max`:
*example: 7 and 11*

```
7 % 11 = 7
7 % 7 = 0
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int tree[3] = {0};
    int max = 0;
    int cut = 0;

    printf("Max Height: "),
    scanf("%d", &max);

    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        printf("Tree%d: ",i+1),
        scanf("%d", &tree[i]);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    {
        cut += (tree[i] % max) % tree[i];
    }
    printf("Amount to remove: %d\n", cut);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

---

In August 2015 (nearly 2 years from the original post), I decided to revisit this question, and come up with a generalized solution.

It look a little work, but the full expression is:

```
int cut = (tree % max % tree) + !!(tree/max) * (tree/max - 1) * max;
```

**Examples:**

```
| Tree | Max | Expression      | Answer |
|    4 |  11 | 0 + 0 * -1 * 11 |      0 |
|   47 |  11 | 3 + 1 * 3 * 11  |     36 |
```

*Note:* My use of !! (double-not) is pretty much a C / C++ only construct.  May not work in other languages.

Comment: +1, probably handles the OP's case, but unfortunately this only holds until `tree[i] >= n*max` where `n > 1`. The answer will include integer division *and* modulo, but this puts the OP on the closest track.

Comment: Will this work if `tree[i]` is, say, 25? You'd get an answer of 3 from the modulus calculations.

Comment: +1 for the statement ***`x%max%x`***.  But an edit to fix the range problem would be good.  Range in your solution is only good for 0<tree<2*tree. (as pointed out by several commenting on this post)

Comment: 2015: I updated my post with a generalized expression.  It involves 4 terms overall, and a double-not.  But it doesn't have the same domain-problem.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a general solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CUTAMOUNT(tr, lim) (tr - lim) * (((2 * tr) - ((2 * tr) % (tr + lim))) / (tr + lim - 1))

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int tree1 = 14;
    int tree2 = 7;
    int tree3 = 16;
    int limit = 11;

    int cutamounttotal = 0;

    cutamounttotal += CUTAMOUNT(tree1, limit);
    cutamounttotal += CUTAMOUNT(tree2, limit);
    cutamounttotal += CUTAMOUNT(tree3, limit);

    printf("Amount to remove: %d\n", cutamounttotal);

    return 0;
}
```

- no branches
- no loops
- no conditionals
- no ternary operations
- no bitwise operations
- no logic operations

Only arithmetic operations.  The trick is to understand that % is the only arithmetic operator which can create a step.  Operands must be sized appropriately to ensure the step only occurs where we want it and nowhere else.  We can then exploit that step to give the desired result.

Comment: Flawless! Gladly eating my words as we speak.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using only absolute value function(abs), division, subtraction, addition.

```
Tree1: 14
Tree2: 7
Tree3: 16

Tree limit: 11

14-11=3 ----->3+abs(3)=6  ----------> 6/2 =3
7-11=-4 ----> -4 + abs(-4)=0 -------------> 0/2=0
16-11=5 -----> 5+abs(5)=10 ------------> 10/2 = 5
...
...
...
3+5 = 8 :D
```

The upper text shows how you convert smaller values to zero. So only bigger values are additively effective.

If you cannot use abs() then you can shift-left + shift-right combo to get absolute value.
But this can go undefined behaviour. Results are implementation-defined for right-shifts of signed values.

Comment: Probably the most general answer, but it just hides the implementation in the `abs()` function, which still must either use `if`, or some kind of trick with bit-shifting or conditionals.

Comment: Not always, it can use the msb bit to broadcast or multiply. For example, Val * msb.AND.1 is the thing.

Comment: "Some kind of trick with bit-shifting or conditionals", in other words.

Comment: Yea, I just couldnt find the exact fiddling :)

Comment: If we cannot hide "if", how others cannot hide cpu-level hardware "if" s ? Shifting left by 1 bit and shifting right by 1 bit just makes msb zero :P

Comment: Hey, it's not my question - I'd just use `if`.

Comment: Can shifting left by 1 time and shifting right by one time, clear the msb always?

Comment: No, left shifting negative numbers is undefined. Right shifting a negative number is implementation defined.

Comment: What about including an assembly code from another package that uses cpu-level shifting instructions?

Comment: Then it wouldn't be C, and the whole question would be moot.

Comment: Okay, can signum function be "if"less ? I suspect it would be same with abs()

Comment: If you can't call `abs` why not [use bit magic to get `MAX(treeSize, limit)`](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerMinOrMax) and call it a day?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little disappointed in myself for giving this question so much thought, but that being said, I'm going to go out on a limb and say there is no general solution for all `n > 0` that either doesn't use an `if` statement, or doesn't use some other kind of trickery to simulate one. I'll gladly eat my words if someone demonstrates me wrong.

For each tree, the obvious and correct solution is:

```
cut = max(height - limit, 0);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
if ( height - limit > 0 ) {
   cut = height - limit;
} else {
   cut = 0;
}
```

or alternatively:

```
if ( height > limit ) {
   cut = height - limit;
} else {
   cut = 0;
}
```

The simplest way (other than using a `max()` function) to simulate this without actually explicitly using an `if` statement is:

```
cut = (height - limit) * (height > limit);
```

since `height > limit` will evaluate to `1` or `0` at the right times.

You can also simulate it with a `while` loop as so:

```
cut = 0;
while ( height > limit ) {
   cut = height - limit;
   break;
}
```

and using a ternary operator is the most blatant way to claim to not use an `if`. There may be other tricks messing with bits, but the story is the same.

It's possible to modify any of these methods to employ the modulo operator as the question asks, but all that achieves is making a simpler algorithm more complex.

I suspect the method in abelenky's answer is the one that's being sought and probably the best overall solution to the question, here, even though it only works for `0 < n < 2 * limit`.

Comment: +1 Best solution.  `cut = (height - limit) * (height > limit)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you've already read in the 3 tree heights into an array:

```
int trees[3];
int limit = 11;
int i;
int cut = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    int cut += trees[i] > limit
             ? (trees[i] / limit - 1) * limit + trees[i] % limit
             : 0;
}
printf("Amount to remove: %d\n", cut);
```

Comment: that's going to return number of trees that need to be cut, not total length to be cut.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT] - Solution for all values of tree, uses % operator, but not ternary:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 11

int modsum(int a, int b, int c) ;

int main()
{
    int results;
    results = modsum(25, 7, 16);
    return 0;
}

int modsum(int a, int b, int c)
{
    int i, suma, sumb, sumc;

    i=0;
    while(a > 2*MAX)
    {
        i++;
        a -= MAX;
    }
    suma = (i*MAX)+(a%MAX%a);

    i=0;
    while(b > 2*MAX)
    {
        i++;
        b -= MAX;
    }
    sumb = (i*MAX)+(b%MAX%b);

    i=0;
    while(c > 2*MAX)
    {
        i++;
        c -= MAX;
    }
    sumc = (i*MAX)+(c%MAX%c);


    return suma+sumb+sumc;

}
```

Comment: How is "a>11 ? " different from "if staement"?

Comment: @MK - It does depend on using the ternary operator, yes, but OP has not answered whether it is out of bounds to do so.

Comment: ternary operator and if are the same thing.

Comment: See edit, provide solution for all values of tree without ternary.

Comment: Using `while` is still cheating, if `if` isn't allowed. Instead of `if ( h > max ) { cut = h - max; } else { cut = 0; }` you could just do `cut = 0; while ( h > max ) { cut = h - max; break; }` Just goes to show what a silly problem this is.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - agreed on the silly part.  But there is a fundamental difference between a keyword that branches and one that loops, no?  Maybe the OP's constraints are designed to teach looping on modulus operators.  Who knows

Comment: @ryyker: Well, there's a fundamental difference between a loop and an `if` statement, for sure, but a loop is just a conditional branch that's tested, potentially, more than once. I suspect that abelenky's answer is the one that's actually expected by the assignment, or close to it, even though it works only for a limited domain.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - abelsnky's answer also uses loops.  More importantly, _there is nothing in the OP description that inhibits use of loops_.  I am just not sure how you are deriving this requirement.

Comment: @ryyker: abelenky's solution only uses loops to sum the results for the three trees, it doesn't use loops to calculate the cut for each individual tree. It's not my requirement, but the way I see it, it's pointless forbidding an `if` but permitting something functionally identical to an `if`, which a loop is as I showed. Same reason the simplest answer, `cut = (h - max) * (h > max);` shouldn't be permitted, because that last `* (h > max)` is functionally identical to `if ( h > max )` in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are allowed to use `*`, `/`, and `>`, you can do it like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int trees[3] = {24, 7, 16};
  int limit = 11;
  int allowedRemainder = 0;
  int mod = 0;
  int modCount = 0;
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
  {
    allowedRemainder = (trees[i] / limit) - 1;
    mod = trees[i] % limit;

    modCount += (allowedRemainder > 0) * (allowedRemainder * limit) +
                (allowedRemainder >= 0) * mod;
    printf("Loop %d: mod = %d\n", i, modCount);
  }
  printf("Amount to remove: %d\n", modCount);
  return 0;
}
```

`(allowedRemainder > 0) * (allowedRemainder * limit)` says if we had at least `limit` more than allowed, add a multiple of `limit` to `modCount`.
`(allowedRemainder >= 0) * mod` says if we had more than `limit`, add the remainder to `modCount`.

[[Sample Code]](https://ideone.com/ra2OJ5)

Comment: This also only works when `tree[n] < (limit * 2)`. If `tree[0]` was 30, for instance, then you end up with `8 * 1`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: Good point, I fixed the logic to deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

Tree heights are in an array, because I'm too lazy to make 3 variables.
It makes use of modulo operator as requested.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  int tree_h[]={14,7,16};
  int limit=11;
  int i;
  int remove=0;

  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    remove+=(tree_h[i]>limit)*(tree_h[i]%limit);
  }
  printf("Amount to remove: %d\n", remove);

  return 0;
}
```